# Xcode 9 breakpoint hold mouse over variable to show contents gone?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

When a breakpoint is triggered I often click and leave my mouse over an objects's name and `Xcode` would show me that object and I could expand it to see the contents.

Now, in `Xcode 9` I can't get this to work. Has something changed? Please tell me I can still do this!

Comment: I can not even use 'fix all in scope' with the new xCode >.<